# Pass absolute file path to --args option of open command OSX

Tags: osx-mavericks, open

I have a script `/usr/local/bin/foo` that opens an app with command line arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a Foo.app --args $@
```

The problem is, when I run

```
foo bar.txt
```

the result is `Foo.app` opens and tells me `bar.txt` cannot be found.
However,

```
foo /absolute/path/to/bar.txt
```

works as expected.

Is there a *simple* way to automatically pass absolute paths to the `--args` option of the open command?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution I could come up with

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $@
do
     ARGS=`realpath $i`" $ARGS"
done

open -a Foo.app --args $ARGS
```

Comment: I would guess this fails with whitespace on the path

Comment: yes. realpath does not like whitespace :(

Comment: No, it's probably solvable by quoting it right, but I don't know by just looking at it where to put them :)